# Functional disequality

Tags: analysis

Let $f \in C^{2}([a,b]) \ $, $f(a)= f(b) = 0 \ $, $f(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in (a,b) \ $, $f(x) + f(x)''>0  \ $. Then $b-a \ge \pi $. 
Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $g(t):=f(t-a)$ (so we can assume that $a=0$). We put $C:=\int_0^bf(t)\sin\left(\frac tb\pi\right)dt$, then $C>0$. Now, since $-f''(t)\leq f(t)$ we have 
\begin{align*}
C&=\left[-f(t)\cos\left(\frac tb\pi\right)\frac b{\pi}\right]_0^b+\int_0^bf'(t)\cos\left(\frac tb\pi\right)\frac b{\pi}dt\\
&=\frac b{\pi}\left(\left[f'(t)\sin\left(\frac tb\pi\right)\frac b{\pi}\right]_0^b-\int_0^bf''(t)\frac b{\pi}\sin\left(\frac tb\pi\right)dt\right)\\
&=-\frac{b^2}{\pi^2}\int_0^bf''(t)\sin\left(\frac tb\pi\right)dt\\
&\leq \frac{b^2}{\pi^2}\int_0^bf(t)\sin\left(\frac tb\pi\right)dt\\
&\leq \frac{b^2}{\pi^2}C,
\end{align*}
and the result follows since $b>0$.